# NodeJS authentication problem with Active Directory B2C using passport.js

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js, nestjs

I'm trying to authenticate with the tokens I get from AAD but for some reason there's a problem that I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Steps

1- I generate a token and the grant type is client credentials, the active directory used is b2c, implicit flow enabled, Id token and Access token selected.

2- I've added a scope and used the below configuration for the bearer strategy

```
super({
  identityMetadata:
    "https://" +
    b2cDomainHost +
    "/" +
    tenantID +
    "/" +
    policyName +
    "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration/",
  clientID: clientID,
  policyName: policyName,
  isB2C: true,
  validateIssuer: false,
  loggingLevel: "info",
  loggingNoPII: false,
  passReqToCallback: false,
}
```

**The error I end up getting is**

```
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"","pid":15354,"level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: We did not receive a token we know how to validate","time":"","v":0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important that client credentials grant flow does not currently **directly** supported Azure AD B2C, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#unsupported-application-types).

> Although the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant flow is not currently
> directly supported by the Azure AD B2C authentication service, you can
> set up client credential flow using [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and the Microsoft
> identity platform `/token` endpoint for an application in your Azure AD
> B2C tenant.

That means `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/` is not supported,

```
// NOT SUPPORT
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

BUT `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` is supported.

```
// SUPPORT
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{b2c-tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<b2c-app-client_id>
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&client_secret=<b2c-app-client_secret>
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Please try the previous supported one.

Comment: I use that to generate the token (the supported one) and to authenticate in the identityMetadata I use the b2clogin.com, I'm able to successfully generate a valid token but passport.js is the one complaining.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if there's something else I have to change in passport.js but it's still this error: We did not receive a token we know how to validate

Comment: Two suggestions for u: 1) try to using passport with normal Azure AD, like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`, 2) follow this b2c [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi) using sign-in user. I will test them later.

Comment: Azure AD works fine with passport, but b2c does not. I've also followed the mentioned sample before and it doesn't work so I'm not sure what can possibly be wrong.

Comment: This because the b2c sample needs you to sign in with a user, it doesn't support client_credentials type.

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense, I've actually tried the same and also the sample is not working when using the same method, I'm not sure how to sign in with a user using an HTTP request, since the client is supposed to get a token and use it on a protected web API

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm doing from the beginning is entirely correct, but the scenario is that I have a protected API that requires AD authentication, I want to leverage AD B2C to generate a token to be able to consume my API, and I'm using b2c since the client is an external user.

Comment: So what you want is to protect API(like `https://contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read`) for external users in Azure B2C. Please follow all steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga). The previous link of b2c sample   only configures to protect the web API. You need to call the API with the single-page application and don't have to generate a token by yourself.

Comment: That one requires user login from the actual application, which is not what I'm supposed to do, the APIs are protected by Active Directory, and it's only available for consumption, there's no login for it, it's needed for integration with other systems so there's no point in having a login page, that's why I have to generate tokens and use them to be able to consume the APIs, thank you :)

Comment: If your Azure AD api and Azure B2C client application are in the same tenant, you could call the api with b2c. The steps are still similar.

Comment: I solved it by following the ROPC flow, It's not a best practice but I don't have a choice for the time being until B2C implements credentials flow.